# subtract 2 dates in JS

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have 2 dates that I want to subtract the difference then compare it to return a simple command on the output.  I have it in a js `for` loop and then doing simple math.

My information is pulled from an API and returns from a JSON response the following:

```
-0: Object
dateTime: "2018-02-14T14:27:00.000Z" //This is what I want to use 
+device: Object
distanceSinceLastValidCoordinate: 0
+driver: Object
eventCode: 4
eventRecordStatus: 1
eventType: 1
id: "atyhJlpX9YEyMdDHG03EA2w"
+location: Object
malfunction: "None"
origin: "Automatic"
sequence: "00000000000006a8"
state: "Active"
status: "ON"
version: "0000000000046700"
```

My code is this:

```
    for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
                   var stTime = results[i].dateTime; //Returns: 2018-02-14T14:27:00.000Z


                   var status = results[i].status;
                   var driver = results[i].driver.id;

                   var today = new Date(); //Returns: 2018-02-14T15:27:27.582Z

                   console.log("Today: ",today);
                   console.log("From Database: ", stTime);


                   var answerThis =  Math.abs(stTime - today); //Retuns: NULL

                   console.log("Answer: ", answerThis)



                   if((answerThis) > 6){

                       console.log("Driver "+ driver +" on "+ stTime + " Has The Status Of " + status);
                   }
                 }
              }),function(e){
                       console.error("Failed: ",e)
                   }
```

It never errors out, just gives a NULL value.

My question is how can I use the dateTime value that is generated and subtract the time from NOW, then if the time is greater than 6hrs, to show the `console.log()`  info in the IF statement?

Comment: Please post a "working" example. The expression `Math.abs(stTime - today)` must return a Number, which might be an integer or NaN. It should never return *null* according to [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-math.abs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go (new Date().getTime() - stTime.getTime()) to give the difference in milliseconds.

```
let timeDifferenceMilliseconds = (new Date().getTime() - stTime.getTime());

let timeDifferenceHours = timeDifferenceMilliseconds / (3600*1000);

if (timeDifferenceHours > 6) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly!  Its now only showing the results that are over 6 hours instead of returning all results!  Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Nice one, glad it works

Comment: This could be simplified to `if (Date.now() - stTime > 2.16e7)`.

Answer (score 0):

replace
`var stTime = results[i].dateTime` 
with 
`var stTime = new Date( results[i].dateTime)`

and

`var answerThis =  new Date(Math.abs(stTime - today));`

```
if(answerThis.getHours() > 6){
    console.log("Driver "+ driver +" on "+ stTime + " Has The Status Of " + status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the milliseconds of those two dates:

```
var stTime = new Date(results[i].dateTime);
var today = new Date();
var answerThis =  Math.abs(stTime.getTime() - today.getTime());
```

After that you could convert answerThis back to Minutes, Hours, Days, whatever you need.